# Fabric's run function does not work in larger scenarios and working fine in smaller ones

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

Here is the full script

```
from fabric.api import run, env, execute

env.hosts = ['root@host',]

def install():
    run('apt-get install git')
    run('apt-get install mercurial')
    run('apt-get install golang')

def set_GOPATH():
    run('echo "export GOPATH=/usr/lib/gopath" > /root/.bash_profile')
    run('export GOPATH=/usr/lib/gopath')

def go_get():
    run('go get "code.google.com/p/log4go"')

def set_ulimit():
    run('ulimit -n 32000')

def get_code():
    run('git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/me/rr.git')

def compile():
    run('cd rr')
    run('go build -o rr example.go')

def run():    
    run('screen -S rr')
    run('./rr')

def doit():
    install()
    setGOPATH()
    go_get()
    set_ulimit()
    get_code()
    compile()
    run()
```

> fab doit

returns the following error:

```
run('apt-get install git')
TypeError: run() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

the same error occurring then running

> fab install

. 
If install function is copied in the separate fabfile with no other functions it is working fine. I don't understand what causes such behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have override fabric's `run` with you own:

```
def run():    
    run('screen -S rr')
    run('./rr')
```

Give it different name and everything should be fine :)